# Converting past gregorianCalendar date with timezone to localDate return bad time

Tags: java, localdate

When I am converting GregorianCalendar to LocalDate I have this problem:

```
System.out.println(((GregorianCalendar) DatatypeConverter.parseDateTime("1945-10-01+02:00")).toZonedDateTime()
        .withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate());
```

return `1945-10-01` what is OK

```
    System.out.println(((GregorianCalendar) DatatypeConverter.parseDateTime("1945-10-02+02:00")).toZonedDateTime()
            .withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate());
```

return same date: `1945-10-01` what is NOT OK

Why ?

My timezone ist Prague. When I check [this](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/czech-republic/prague?year=1945) side +2h should be till 18.11 not till 10.1

Comment: What exactly you are trying to achieve?

Comment: converting GregorianCalendar to LocalDate

Comment: I get the correct dates, even after setting "Europe/Prague" as the default time zone. So I can't reproduce your issue.

Comment: I have reproduced on Java 11 since it thinks the transition happened on October 1. I cannot reproduce on Java 8 nor on 9, they agree with you about November 18.

Comment: it is sad this is not backward compatibility because we just upgrade from java 8 to java 11 and we dont know about this problem

Comment: I understand. If you had stayed on Java 8, you would still have had the same problem if you had just updated the timezone data (there’s a tool for doing that in an existing Java installation). It’s not often they change data for 1945 (I think), but the data for present and future dates are changed all the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java Time API relies on [IANA Time Zone Database](https://www.iana.org/time-zones). According to it, time shift had happened on 10.1:

```
Rule    Czech   1945    only    -   Oct  1  2:00s   0   -
```

Comment: hm thx nice point. But why I get different information on the site which I post ?

Comment: Probably because the site you've posted uses another source of daylight saving time history

Answer (score 0):

You may just omit the time zone conversion:

```
        System.out.println(((GregorianCalendar) DatatypeConverter.parseDateTime("1945-10-02+02:00")).toZonedDateTime()
                .toLocalDate());
```

> 1945-10-02

Or parse yourself without the `DatatypeConverter`:

```
        System.out.println(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE
                .parse("1945-10-02+02:00", LocalDate::from));
```

> 1945-10-02

(Curious about whether IANA or timeanddate.com is correct; I usually place high confidence in both. One possible explanation would be if timeanddate.com relies on an older IANA database version.)

Comment: I need to use DatatypeConverter because of converting XSD string date to localdate where XSD support a lots of different string format which is already included in DatatypeConverter